# Select-React Rest-Api Не работает поиск?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Передаю данные из Rest-api в option у select-react, но не могу понять как настроить поиск, в документации нету примера, а тот который есть написан через typescript. Искал разные решения, но там или очень старые или же поиск так же не работает.

Снизу прилагаю код.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import dummy from './dummy';
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

function SelectsDrop() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [inputValue, setValue] = useState('');
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('null');

    const fetchData = () => {
        return dummy.get(`/country`).then(result => {
            const res = result.data.data;
            return res;
        });
    }

    const handleInputChange = value => {
        setValue(value);
    };
    // handle selection
    const handleChange = value => {
        setSelectedValue(value);
    }

        return (
            <div className="city__select">
                Selected Value: {JSON.stringify(selectedValue || {}, null, 2)}
                <AsyncSelect
                    components={{DropdownIndicator}}
                    placeholder={"Выбор страны"}
                    cacheOptions
                    defaultOptions
                    getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
                    getOptionValue={e => e.id}
                    styles={customStyles}
                    loadOptions={fetchData}
                    onInputChange={inputValue}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />

            </div>
        )

}
export default SelectsDrop;
```

Comment: Из документации https://react-select.com/async свойство loadOptions - функция, с параметром inputValue, по нему и можно делать поиск, например, `/country?query=${inputValue}`

Comment: @SergeyPhilippenko Я смотрел в документации, там берется 2 функции filterColors и loadOptions. Я пытался их переписать, в итоге вообще ничего не передается в options